# How to show datavisualization line chart start from 0 and maximum value 50 at Y-Axis in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, charts, data-visualization, linechart

I want to display a line series chart using datavisualization in Windows Phone 8, whose Y-axis value always starts from 0 and having maximum range value 50.It means all the times it should display grid lines from 0 to 50 values with interval equals to 5.

I implemented the line chart but the problem i am facing is that suppose Y-axis data value is{10,14,24,31} then chart will default starts from 10 to 35. How to give starting value as 0 and maximum value as 50 for the chart?

Comment: What library are you using to draw this Graph?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware Using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll